# RSpec integration test error trouble in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, integration-testing, factory-bot

Please understand that I cannot speak English well.
I'm having trouble with the rails rspec error not being resolved.
Rails web app login integration test error.
I'll attach the error and test details here.

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aqIs.png)
[test details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7MA7.png)

I designed the controller's create method to "redirect to home after login".
[create method for "login and redirect to home"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVlvs.png)
And it has been confirmed that it returns to home after logging in on the development server. But it doesn't work in integration tests.
I wondered why.
Perhaps the user data prepared for testing is not loaded properly?
so i can't redirect to home after login?
[Factory bot gems and user data generation files required to create RSpec test user data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JflO.png)
[gem for tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp97u.png)
As an aside, this is my first time writing integration tests in RSpec.
So there may be some rookie mistakes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't link to screenshots of code. Please edit your question and include the code directly into your question as text.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll try edit.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FactoryBot.build(:user)` initializes a user in memory, but doesn't save it into the database. That means the login fails, because a user with that email is not found in the database. And because the login failed, the user is still on `/login`.

To fix this, just change

```
before do
  @user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
end
```

to

```
before do
  @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
end
```

in your `user_login_spec.rb`.

Comment: solved!
you are amazing!
thank you!
I will do my best!